# Advantages and disadvantages in term of radar performance of LFM chirp

Tags: radar

Which are the advantages and disadvantages of a LFM chirp regarding its radar performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is not homework, you can summarize LFM performance as

**Advantanges**

- LFM is easy to implement in hardware - even more so if you can use stretch (de-chirp) processing. It has been the most popular type of pulse compression.
- Good range resolution which is a function of bandwidth.
- Autocorrelation (matched filter output) has good side-lobe levels.
- The LFM spectrum is "nice" given its sharp band edges. This make it more robust to signal processing chains with lots of filtering.
- LFM is Doppler tolerant. This means that the matched-filter output (think SNR) is robust to Doppler shifts from the return signal.

**Disadvantages**

- LFM exhibits range-Doppler coupling. A Doppler shift will shift the peak of the matched filter output to a different delay (range).